# Is there a ground cover that will choke out plants from growing up through it while letting established trees survive in zone 4a?

Tags: weed-control

Last year I had a disastrous Canadian thistle problem, and am wondering if I can do anything to choke out the thistle, and any grass from popping up. I know some plants will kill trees, but will anything kill grass, and Canadian Thistle in the area? I get plenty of water in the area, so once established it will be fine, and grow.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, not to choke out the thistle nor the grass, both will need to be dealt with, either by digging out or treating with selective herbicides. You will likely need one herbicide for grass and another for the thistle, unless you use one that kills anything it touches, which may not be wise if there are other plants in the area you want to keep. Further info here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/weeds/canada-thistle-control.htm